# How to write this logical expression with Gurobi + Java, or express it as a big-m formulation

Tags: modeling, integer-programming, gurobi, logical-constraints, indicator-constraints

I am trying to write the following expression in Gurobi+Java or Gurobi+python, if it is more practical It could be expressed as a big-M formulation.

\begin{equation} \label{const4}
    \text{D}_{uv} =
  \begin{cases}
    \quad 0       & \quad \text{if } \quad Z_{uv}+Z_{vu} = 1\\
    \quad 0.3  & \quad \text{if } \quad Z_{uu}+Z_{vv} = 2 \\
    \quad 0.7  & \quad \text{if } \quad P_{u}= 1 \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

the variable $D_{uv}$ is used in a minimization objective function, where $C_{uv}$ is the parameter cost. I want to update the value for the variable $D_{uv}$, according to the behaviour of variable $Z_{uv}$ and $P_{u}$.

\begin{equation}
f_{min}= \sum_{(u,v) \in P(i,j)} C_{uv} (\text{D}_{uv})
\end{equation}

I used the method GRBModel.AddGenConstrIndicator() (Gurobi+Java), but, when any of the conditions are fulfilled I do not see any changes in the value for variable $D_{uv}$, it does not change at all.

I want to express these conditional statements using the indicator constraints by gurobi, if it is not possible, I would like to use a big-M formulation. I have tried to express the conditional statements as big-M formulations without success.

Comment: What exactly is relation between UB and $Z_{u,v}$? Because if $D_{u,v}$ can only take values in $\{0.5,0.9\}$, then UB will remain 1.

Comment: @RobPratt If non of the condition holds, the value for $D_{uv}$ is going to be zero. And I think the subscipts are ok, I checked the LP file and I changed manually the values for the UB. Thanks.

Comment: @Sutanu UB is the value for the upper bound of variable $D_{UV}$. $D_{UV}$ is a discount factor than can take value of 0.5 when $Z_{uv}$ + $Z_{vu}$=1, 0.9 when $Z_{uu}$ + $Z_{vv}$=2, or 0 when non of those conditions are achieved. The value for $Z$ variable is subject to other constraints. I solved the current formulation, and I saw that some of these conditions are achieved, but the value for $D_{uv}$ remains equal to 1. Thank you.

Comment: Try making UB as a variable. Add constraint $D_{u,v} \le UB$, remove UB as upper bound while creating D and also add any relation of UB with Z as a constraint.

Comment: @Hernan19, you defined $D$ as a binary variable while its results would be a float number. Are you sure it is correct?

Comment: @A.Omidi you are right. But, still when I change the variable to "GRB.CONTINOUS", the expected changes in the value of $D_{uv}$ do not occur.

Comment: @RobPratt thanks for your comment. When $(Z_{uu},Z_{vv})=(1,1)$ the value for $D_{uv}$ will be equal to 0.3, if and only if $u$ and $v$ are neighbors, neither case $D_{uv}$  will be equal to zero. When we have a path composed by the following pattern  $(Z_{uu} -- P_{u+1}-- Z_{vv}$, then $D_{uv}$ will be equal to 0.7, but,  if and only if all of the three variables are neighbors, with that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

What about:
$ \delta_1,\delta_2$ binary

$D_{uv} = 0.3\delta_1 + 0.7\delta_2$

$1-z_{min}(1 - \delta_3) \le z_{uv}+z_{vu}\le 1+z_{max}(1-\delta_3)$

$ 2 - z_{min}(1-\delta_2) \le z_{uu}+z_{vv}\le 2 + z_{max}(1-\delta_2) $

$1-z_{min}(1-\delta_1) \le z_{uu} \le 1 + z_{max}(1-\delta_1) $

$ \delta_1+\delta_2 +\delta_3 = 1$

If using indicator variable for [Gurobi](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_agc_indicator.html),

```
model.addGenConstrIndicator(delta[1],1,z[u,u]==1)
   
model.addGenConstrIndicator(delta[2],1,z[u,u]+z[vv]==2)
            
model.addGenConstrIndicator(delta[3],1,z[u,v]+z[v,u]==1)
        
model.addConstr(delta.sum()==1)
```